# Missing plug-in when IE /Chrome is launched via automation

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Just a quick question: I have a plug in (an .exe file) that I have downloaded and installed in my Internet Explorer. The issue I am facing is that, when I launch IE via automation, the plugin is absent and I cannot successfully complete the automation test as the plugin must be there. How Can I launch IE in automation with that .exe file right there? Do I need to perfom additional task after I have launched the IE browser? any reason why the application launched via automation is missing the .exe file but the manually launched one has the file well installed?

Note: I am noticing same when I launch Chrome via automation. (the .exe file is there when manually launched.)

System infos:
Internet Explorer v 11.
OS: 64 bit - Windows 10
Webdriver= installed a 32 bit to speed up issue when filling in some text, as I noticed that texts were filled 1 by 1 one with some 2-5 seconds delay.

Comment: Each time selenium launches a fresh browser window. It will not have any setting or plugins which was present in your local session and hence it will not have that exe. Inorder to get that exe in the browser session launched by selenium you need to rely on profile

Comment: Looks like "Profile" is only related to Firefox, Anything for IE, or Chrome? When I use this :    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
instance = new FirefoxDriver(profile);   where "path" is the path directory to my created profile, Things still fail, because that "path" is not the path of the webdriver., Shall I have the driver.exe file also right in there?

Comment: You can find something related to chrome profile here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/854. And as you said instance = new FirefoxDriver(profile) is no longer valid in latest version. Instead use FirefoxOptions to set a profile https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#setProfile-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile-